# NSLayoutConstraint Prevents NSWindow Resizing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nslayoutconstraint

I am adding some simple constraints to an NSView that I have in my main NSWindow but it is causing problems.

Normally I can resize my application window (just like any Safari/Finder window etc.). I add a simple NSView to my window like so:

```
[self.blackDimOverlay setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];
        [self.blackDimOverlay setAlphaValue:0.5f];
        [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.blackDimOverlay];
```

This works as expected. I then add two constraints to this view so that it stays the full size of the window when resized.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_blackDimOverlay);
        NSArray *constraintHorizontalOverlay = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_blackDimOverlay]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict];
        NSArray *constraintVerticalOverlay = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_blackDimOverlay]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict];
        [self.window.contentView addConstraints:constraintHorizontalOverlay];
        [self.window.contentView addConstraints:constraintVerticalOverlay];
```

However, after adding these two constraints, they lock my window up, so I can't resize it anymore. Everything else works as normal, but the constraints block any window resizing.

How can I keep my subview the full-size of my window while being able to resize my window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are additional constraints on `_blackDimOverlay` which dictate its size and are of higher priority than `NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCanResizeWindow`. You can investigate using:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.window.contentView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal]);
NSLog(@"%@", [self.window.contentView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical]);
```

Most likely, you forgot to do `[_blackDimOverlay setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]`.

Alternatively, the view class of which `_blackDimOverlay` is an instance defines an intrinsic size and its hugging and compression-resistance priorities are higher than `NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCanResizeWindow`. You would need to reduce those priorities using `-setContentHuggingPriority:forOrientation:` and `-setContentCompressionResistancePriority:forOrientation:`.